# Google Measurement Protocol (GA4) events not showing on dashboard

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

I've implemented GA4 but, when I try to send event, its not showing in dashboard.
When I change the project, its working, also the configuration is done.
By the way, I've read and tried a lot of questions about this problem in SO but nothing works for now.

How can I solve the problem ?

I've used Measurement Protocol API to send events,
Also test with Postman as well and result is same.

Comment: First ensure that they're showing up in DebugView and RealTime view. Then for them to end up in your actual reports it can take 24-48hrs.

Comment: Hi, I'm sure that its not showing up in DebugView or RealTime view or reports, it passed over 1 month since I tested with first event.

Comment: I can see the events for my other project, but this project converted from UA to GA4, maybe there was a problem with Google side, how can I investigate this one ?

Comment: Can you post a copy of what you're sending to the sever?

Comment: I'll but its nothing related with payload, because its showing in one project, but not other one.

Comment: To exclude payload, you'd jfust have to confirm you have a URI that matches the measurement_id and api_secret. Confirming that, you'd have to ensure debug view is not capturing your request and that your payload includes debug_view: 1. Failing that I would very much suspect something is malformed in the payload.

Comment: Payload is okay, because, I've successfully saw events on other project. I guess there is a problem with configuration on the Google side, maybe there was a problem migrating UA to MP.